# filesystem image mounted with lofiadm looks smaller than expected

Tags: mount, solaris

I have a .gz file and I'd like to see the content of it. I used lofiadm to mount it.

```
lofiadm /backup/file.gz ->>  returned /dev/lofi/1
mount -F ufs /dev/lofi/1 /mnt
```

Then I checked the content

```
/mnt> du -sh *
4K   etc
79M   kernel
8K   lost+found
13M   platform
```

The problem is size  of file.gz was around 342 MB but the content is around 93 MB.
I checked it with `ls -al` but there were no other file.

```
/dev/lofi/1            321M    93M   196M    33%    /mnt
```

Now I don't understand how that happens. File size was 342 MB but after mount it returns 92 MB

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `lofiadm`, so I may be missing something, but I don't see anything strange. You have a filesystem with 321MB of space, of which 93MB is used and the rest is empty. The empty space may or may not be filled with easily-compressible data, so the fact that it's unused implies nothing about how well it can be compressed. The image is a little over 321MB, with extra space used for bookkeeping (inode tables).

Answer (score 1):

Your file.gz file doesn't seem to be compressed at all given the fact you are mounting it as is, i.e. without decompressing it:

```
lofiadm /backup/file.gz ->>  returned /dev/lofi/1
```

The file system reported size is 321MB which is consistent with a 342 MB "device", as Gilles already answered.